# Unresolvable broken dependencies, none of 'apt-get' commands works

Tags: linux, package-management, apt-get, apt, dependencies

Before I explain the problem, I should say that I have tried all other answers to similar questions and troubleshootings around the Internet, and none of them works. To be more specific all `apt-get` commands like:

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get -f upgrade
apt-get -f dist-upgrade
apt-get -f autoclean
...
```

All of them report `Unable to correct dependencies`.
Based on what apt-get reports, It seems that some essential packages are removed(by me accidentally). For instance:

```
linux-image-2.6... depends on linux-base (>=2.6...) but it is not installed 
depends initramfs-tools (...) but it is not installed ...
```

I know that a lot of packages have been removed because of my wrong modification of `source.list` entries and here I am stuck with a broken system.

My question is there anyway that Linux automatically downloads all its required packages?
Note that I restored `source.list` file and `apt-get update` works fine now.

**Update**
Since I was unable to install or upgrade because of chained dependencies issues, I choose another approach and instead of trying installing packages, I removed all packages with dependencies problem! I used these commands:

```
apt-get -f remove <pkg name>
apt-get -f autoremove
apt-get autoclean
dpkg -r <pkg name>
dpkg --configure <pkg name>
```

Now a lot of packages have been removed, but I have a working shell so I installed aptitude and some fundamental packages using `pat-get install <pkg name>` which now works. I checked installed packages on my system and it seems that only 350 MB of standard ~700 MB (installed by default by Debian) packages now are installed on my system.

A quick search on the internet and I found `tasksel` so I installed it by `apt-get install tasksel`. Now I am trying to restore removed packages with the help of `tasksel`.

***tl;dr*** I removed packages with dependencies issues instead of resolving their dependencies, because of huge number of packages that had to be installed.

Comment: Have you run apt-get update after restoring sources.list? Have you tried to install those dependencies: apt-get install linux-base - are there error messages?

Comment: yes as I said, `apt-get update` works fine, but `apt-get install linux-base` (with -f and without it) raises package dependencies error. I also did `apt-get -f install` but still dependency error. no matter what I do I always get `unable to correct dependencies`

Comment: You could try to install all missing dependencies together: "apt-get install linux-base initramfs-tools" a.s.o. Or use dpkg (which apt relies on): dpkg -i linux-base - in general I would try the latter to fix all dependencies first

Comment: There were a dozen of missing packages like linux-base, initramfs-tools and so on, when I tried to manually install them all with `apt-get -f install ...` more dependencies appear to be missing! right now there are more than 100 I guess, is there any command to automatically fetch missing dependencies and download them?